# I want to convert json according to my format

Tags: android-studio

// I am converting sqlite data into json format

try

{

```
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            String dbDir= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+getResources().getString(R.string.folderName);;
            db=getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(dbDir + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.dbName), Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from products", null);
            Log.e("fetch_category", "" + c.getCount());

            if (c.getCount() == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                c.moveToFirst();
                JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
                do
                {
                    int totalColumn = c.getColumnCount();

                    for( int i=0 ;  i< totalColumn ; i++ )
                    {
                        if( c.getColumnName(i) != null )
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if( c.getString(i) != null )
                                {
                                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", c.getString(i) );

                                    rowObject.put(c.getColumnName(i) ,  c.getString(i) );
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    rowObject.put( c.getColumnName(i) ,  "" );
                                }
                            }
                            catch( Exception e )
                            {
                                Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage()  );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  //  billsModel=new Bills_model();
                    resultSet.put(rowObject);

                    Log.d("resultset",resultSet.toString());
                }

                while (c.moveToNext());
            }

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

//out put is coming like this

[{"key","value"},{"key","value"}....]

//but i want to like this is it possible

{"product"[{"key","value"},{"key","value"}....]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//do following

JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject();

//and then  put all array inside json object it will give desire result

jobj.put("products",resultSet.put(rowObject));

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jackson library -

1. Create a response class.
2. Use @JsonProperty annotation -

@JsonProperty("product")
private String jsonArray;

//getter

//setter

3. Set your json response string in the response object.

Comment: ,i have another one question now first i want to fetch data from sqlite database and i want to conver like;

Comment: [{"bill_date":"30-09-2016","bill_list":[{"id":"144","invoice_no":"INV11255"}]},]